# JWT base64 token decoding with Azure Front door rules

Tags: azure, jwt

We need to route web application users based on values within the jwt token from the request header (from fed proxy) to the correct backend instance (Azure single tenant model). We are planning to use Azure Front Door to do the dynamic routing based on the request header. However, the jwt header is base64 encoded and unfortunately Azure Front Door does not have the ability to decode base64 encoded values from reading through the documentation. The current rules setup supported by Front Door rules engine condition matching are only “To lowercase”, “To uppercase”, “Trim”, “Remove nulls”, “URL encode” and “URL decode”.

Has anyone encountered this and any ideas to solve the issue would be appreciated.

Thank you